# Updating Records Via RowVersion , using 'SQL WHERE' to filter for a MAX Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to update a table based off a RowVersion value in existing table. My data lake updates once a week , with new data stored as a .json file, which holds any new RowVersions.

I need to:

1)Query the existing table in my data warehouse to find the most up to date RowVersion( ie max)

2)Use that value to only filter/select the records in my data warehouse that are greater than the RowVersion I just identified

3)Update my table to include the new Rows

My Question is - the SQL Below, I am not sure how to select the Max RowNumber in the current table and then use that to filter/specify what I want returned when querying my S3 Bucket:

```
create or replace temporary table UPDATE_CAR_SALES AS
SELECT 
VALUE:CAR::string AS CARS,
VALUE:RowVersion::INT AS ROW_VERSION
having row_version > max(row_version)
from '@s3_bucket',
 lateral flatten( input => $1:value);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how you store the data. Is the CARS column unique? Do you need to find maximum row version for each car or for all cars/rows? Anyway you can use a sub-query to filter the rows having row version is higher than the max value:

```
create or replace temporary table UPDATE_CAR_SALES AS 
SELECT 
VALUE:CAR::string AS CARS,
VALUE:RowVersion::INT AS ROW_VERSION
FROM @s3_bucket, lateral flatten( input => $1 )
where ROW_VERSION > (SELECT MAX(RowVersion) 
from MAIN_TABLE);
```

If you need to filter the rows, based on row version of each car (of the existing table):

```
create or replace temporary table UPDATE_CAR_SALES AS 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT
VALUE:CAR::string AS CARS,
VALUE:RowVersion::INT AS ROW_VERSION
FROM @s3_bucket, lateral flatten( input => $1 )) temp_table
where temp_table.ROW_VERSION > (SELECT MAX(RowVersion) 
from MAIN_TABLE where cars = temp_table.CARS );
```

I needed to put the main query in brackets to be able to use alias. Hope it helps.